# Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows ... or when the subquery is used as an expression

Tags: sql, subquery

I know subquery return more than 1 value but I don't know how to change the code. Can anyone help me ?

```
declare @sProjectNumber nvarchar(200)

( select Project from Project_Table where  Project in (
            select case 
            when @sProject is null then (select distinct Project from Project_Table)
            else @sProject end
from Project_Table)
)
```

Comment: You should explain the logic you are trying to implement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am guessing that you really intend something like this:

```
select Project
from Project_Table
where @sProject is NULL or Project = @sProject;
```

This will return the project in `@sProject` or all projects if that value is `NULL`.

Comment: The query is just part of data source for an SSRS report where @sProject is a report parameter NULL by default.

Comment: @Dmana . . . That further suggests that this is what you want.